# Example of nonuniqueness of asymptotes of a ray

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, examples-counterexamples

Let $(M, g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and let $\gamma : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a ray, i.e. a unit speed geodesic such that for every $s, t \ge 0$ :
$$
dist\big(\gamma(s), \gamma(t)\big) = |s - t|.
$$
Let us fix a point $p \in M$. We can define a family $(\sigma_t)_{t \ge 0}$ of segments joining $p$ to $\gamma(t)$. Is it easy to prove that there exist a sequence $(t_i)_i$ such that the segment $(\sigma_{t_i})_i$ converge pointwise to a new ray $\gamma_p$ emanating from $p$. Such a ray is called *asymptote* for $\gamma$. I know that in general an asymptote is not unique but I would like to see a concrete example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a $$\{ (x,y,z)| x^2+y^2=1,\ z\geq 0\} $$

We have a complete manifold $M_1$ by making a suitable $cap$ around
$z=0$ And around $(x-2+\epsilon )^2+y^2=1$ we do same thing so that
we have $M_2$ Here they are intersect along $x=
\frac{2-\epsilon}{2}$ So by cutting along the intersection and
deleting we attach them And by small perturbation we have smooth
manifold $M$ Here for $z<0$ it is like two mountains which are
adjacent.

Let $c$ be a ray $(-1,0,t),\ t\geq 0 $ And fix a point $p=(\frac{
 2-\epsilon}{2},0,z_0)$ where $z_0$ is smallest. Then at $p$ we have
 two asymptotes wrt $c$

Comment: I can not understand why there should be two asymptotes.. One asymptote is the ray starting from the point $(0, 0, -\epsilon)$ and going over the ray. But who is the other one?
Anyhow, thank you very much for paying attention to my questions. :)

Comment: Yes you're right I wil fix some